# dajaxice.core.js not updated with functions in ajax.py

Tags: django, dajaxice, dajax

I'm running Django (1.4.3) with dajaxice (0.5.4). I have a file `ajax.py` with my functions in the main project folder called `prj`, which looks like:

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register
from django.utils import simplejson
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_functions
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse, resolve

def getContent(request, *args, **kwargs):
    url = kwargs['url']
    try:
        v = resolve(url)
    except:
    data = []
    data.append(('some','data'))
    return simplejson.dumps(data)
dajaxice_functions.register(getContent)
```

I ran `python manage.py collectstatic`, and I get the following output:

```
Copying '/tmp/tmpm8OlOw'
```

However, the `dajaxice.core.js` generated does *not* have my function `getContent` at all. Where am I going wrong? I have dajaxice installed properly and everything, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you forgot to call `dajaxice_autodiscover()` from `urls.py` (this is the place recommended by dajaxice author)

this call will load ajax.py module and make it's method discoverable by JS code generator

Answer (score 0):

You need to register you function with dajaxice either using @dajaxice_register decorator or other methods mention in the documentation.

http://django-dajaxice.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#create-your-first-ajax-function